# nodejs filter posts like in instagram feed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, mongoose

I am building an custom backend for instagram like app.

Basically there are users,pages that user can follow.When i want to get posts from collection named ***posts*** i want to get posts from users and pages i follow.

How i can achieve this kind of result?
(i used `Post.find({page:{$in:user.followingPages},creator:{$in:user.followingUsers}})` but this method gives me only the posts that match both condition, i need the post that match either of them or both)

Below is my ***User*** model

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      default: 'nesibeyyubov',
    },
    bio: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    followingUsers: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
    posts: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: Post
      },
    ],
    followingPages: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Page',
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

This is ***Post*** model

```
const postSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    post: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    creator: {
      type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'User'
      required: true,
    },
    likes: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
      },
    ],
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comma means **and** , you should write **$or**.

```
YourModel.find( { $or: [
            { page: { $in: user.followingPages } },
            { creator: { $in: user.followingUsers } },
   ],
} );
```